# NodeJS - JSON as DB & Corrupted data on close

Tags: json, database, node.js

I have a large file that is almost constantly updated (around 10MB but will grow to +100MB)

It is JSON and I am using it as a database. I don't want to use Mongo in this case because it needs to live self contained on a client machine (I am using electron to package it) And because it will be distributed to windows I am also trying to avoid any compiled code.

The problem is it gets corrupted when node closes. I have tried saving it to a .tmp file and then renaming it once done, which has reduced the number of corrupted incidents, but is there a better way (or a native JS DB system)? I don't need querying, just load and save.

Comment: How about an in memory store like redis?

Comment: Cheers, what ended up being the problem was not the way it was written but consecutive writes to the file. You want something that is going to only write to it once at a time. I devised a queuing system that would store up the pending writes and perform them only when another had finished and that has solved the issues